# What are some good mobile devices (phones, tablets, etc.) for tinkering?

Tags: graphics-programming, mobile

I'm looking for a good coder's device to experiment with graphics programming. I'm sure a lot of you must have favorites. It'd be a great help if we can compile a list of these devices.

Just to be clear, I'm interested in devices which are easy to hack. There are good devices like the iPhone, for example, but you can't use a custom WebKit build with it to test WebGL.

So, what are some good 'coder's mobile device's?

Comment: -1 Because your question is too broad. Gathering general information on devices for mobile game testing would be better achieved with a Community Wiki. Otherwise I recommend you rephrase your question so that it can be definitively answered.

Comment: uh.. I would, if I could. Don't have the rep for that. Couldn't you?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't, only moderators can convert a question to a community wiki. However, you should have enough rep to create a community wiki when first posting your question, giving you the option to delete the question and ask it as a community wiki if the issue comes up again.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess would be to look into the Android system : the OS is open source, and lot's of custom ROM are available online. You can also find a lot of Open Source application (including the default browser based on WebKit).

Then if you choose Android, be carefull of which hardware you choose as some manufacturer / carrier make their custom OS fork with limitations (which won't be a problem if you install a custom ROM). My first choice would go to the "official" [Google phone](http://android.brightstarcorp.com/index.htm)

Answer (score 1):

I've gotten good results from a Nook Color running Android 2.3 (specifically, Cyanogen Mod 7) from an SD card. When the card is in, it's basically a rooted Galaxy Tab; when the card is out, it's an unmodified Nook still under its warranty!